# jquery sticky background scroll

Tags: jquery, parallax

I want to achieve something like this;

http://wind-dance.com/sticky/

I want the html to fixed position until the image scroll till bottom. Currently my script coded it will scroll along with html scroll.

Is there any jquery script that could achieve similar effect that I want?

**UPDATE 1**

Maybe my question above is not clear. I changed the way of question then. I want to scroll the div element without scrolling the body content till the div element reached the bottom. Hope this make clear to everyone. And the inline script is my current code that I could achieve partial of it.

**UPDATE 2**

Looking at @bhavesh solution, I tried to modify it into this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var row = $('.row');
    var scroll_banner = $('.scroll_banner');
    var scroll_banner_height = scroll_banner.height();
    var row_height = row.height();

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        scroll_banner_height = scroll_banner.height();
        var windowPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        var scrollableAmount = windowPos / row_height * scroll_banner_height;
        row.scrollTop(scrollableAmount);
    })
});
```

It very bad scrolling and feel jumpy experience by having scrollTop on body on each scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the inline script in your example
Basically in this example you are attaching On Window Scroll event with div scroll (which contains the image) using scrollTop property.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var row = $('.row');
    var scroll_banner = $('.scroll_banner');
    var scroll_banner_height = scroll_banner.height();
    var row_height = row.height();

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var windowPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        var oldRowPos = row.scrollTop();
        row.scrollTop(oldRowPos+windowPos);
        var newRowPos = row.scrollTop();
        console.log([scroll_banner_height-row_height,newRowPos]);
        if (newRowPos < (scroll_banner_height-row_height)) {
            $(this).scrollTop(0);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Ya this is the one that I coded but not completed to my need.

Comment: @WaiMun I've updated the code to achieve what you were looking for. You have to keep in mind the new position of row being scrolled with window scroll amount. And the magic is happening where you reset window scroll top to 0.

Comment: yes this is the one... but onmousescroll is very laggy... but ondrag scrollbar looks great... any idea to overcome the mousescroll??